# How I can link objects of one Class, to objects of another Class in Java?

Tags: java, class, object

I'm very new to programming and I need some help with my homework. I'like to know if the following is possible, and how.
Let's say I have 2 classes, `class Course` and `class Student`. Many objects can be born from these classes, for example:

`Course 1 obj` `Course 2 obj`

`Student 1 obj` `Student 2 obj` `Student 3 obj` `Student 4 obj`

My question is, how I can relate the objects of `Student class`, to the objects of `Course class`? I want to make something like this:

`Course 1 obj`: Has objects `Student 1`, `2`, `4` 
`Course 2 obj`: Has objects `Student 2`, `4`

Our teacher said we should create another class that holds the `Student objects` for each `Course object`, but I don't understand how I must do this.

By far, I've created `Student objects` and stored them in an `ArrayList`. I did the same with `Course objects`.
But I'm really stuck how to link one to another.

Answer (score 2):

If i am getting the question right, you want to map **Course** to **Student(or list of student)**.
There are several ways to do that and one of them is by using **Hashtable< Key,Value >**.
In most basic sense, Hashtable is a table of Key/Value pairs in which each key is mapped/linked to a value.

a generic code sample related to the data given by you :

```
ArrayList<Student> list1 = new ArrayList<Student>();
list1.add(Student1);
list1.add(Student2);
list1.add(Student4);

ArrayList<Student> list2 = new ArrayList<Student>();
list1.add(Student2);
list1.add(Student4);

Hashtable<Course,ArrayList<Student>> hashTable = new 
Hashtable<Course,ArrayList<Student>>();

hashTable.put(Course1,list1);
hashTable.put(Course2,list2);
```

To get the value(Student list in this case) linked to the key(Course in this case), you just need to call the **get(Key)** method

```
ArrayList<Student> list3 = hastTable.get(Course1);//this will return the value(list1) mapped/linked to the key(Course1)
```

for more information on Hashtable refer to https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Hashtable.html

Answer (score 1):

I think what you're looking for is to create a `Course class` and then inside it, create a list (`ArrayList`) of students (`Student` class). This `Student` class is a different class that is only used inside the `Course`.